# Where to add subviews and constraints for a custom view based on iOS library objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uislider

I would like to made a custom view like this :

[image]

As you can see, this view relies only on objects from iOS library : UILabel and UISlider.
I want to add as many "element" (name + slider + percentage) as I want. So I was thinking of creating just a "unit" view like this :

[image]

and then, adding the number I want programmatically.

So, in order to this, I have to create a new UIView file, but then, where do I add the UILabels, UISlider ? In initWithFrame method ? Are the constraints also to put in this method ? or maybe in "viewDidLoad" method ?

Thanks for your guidance

Comment: There is no one right way to do this. You have defined a moderately complex problem that you want to solve. So you need to break it up and tackle it piece by piece. SO Isn't really a "tell me how to implement my idea" site.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a custom init.
For example:

```
   -(instancetype)initWithLabelText:(NSString*)text andSliderValue:(NSInteger)sliderValue {...}
```

in the custom view class you have global properties for the slider and the labels. which gets initialized with the passed values. the method to change the slider value and the label you add to that class as well

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class and make it inherit from `UIView`.
Then create public properties for all the UI elements you want to control. Alternatively, make the UI elements private and have public counterparts for their value.
Override `layoutSubviews()` to add UI elements as subviews (make sure you don't add them multiple times by checking for nil) and update their frames.
Alternatively, add them in your init function and add auto-layout constraints if you don't want to deal with frames.

Here's a good starting point:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    // MARK: -------------------------
    // MARK: Properties

    var nameLabel: UILabel!
    var slider: UISlider!
    var percentLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: -------------------------
    // MARK: Initialization

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Anything that needs to be initialized when loaded from xib or storyboard
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Anything that needs to be initialized when loaded programatically
    }

    // MARK: -------------------------
    // MARK: Layout

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if nil == nameLabel {
            nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
            // Set other attributes here
            addSubview(nameLabel)
        }

        // Update the name label frame here

        if nil == slider {
            slider = UISlider(frame: CGRectZero)
            // Set other attributes here
            addSubview(slider)
        }

        // Update the slider frame here

        if nil == percentLabel {
            percentLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
            // Set other attributes here
            addSubview(percentLabel)
        }

        // Update the percent label frame here
    }

}
```